# Write a program which takes input in alphanumeric and display only string in reverse order

Tags: java

I was asked a question to write a program which takes an input like `"G12OA43"` and the output must contain only letters and the string must be in a reverse order. like `"AOG"`.
So can any one tell how to write this using Java?

Comment: Well, have you at least tried anything yet?

Comment: We are willig to help you. But we won't write the program for you. So show your own approach first.

Comment: Actually its good 'try yourself and learn' exercize. try using String and Array API for it. All the best.

Comment: Using `for` loop and `String.toCharArray`.

Comment: You must try it first. Then if you face issues post for solutions with your code.

Comment: you try it with string split or regular expression

Answer (score 5):

Because this is clearly a homework question, I am not going to give you the full answer. Instead, I am going to say to take a look at the [`StringBuilder API`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html). `StringBuilder` contains a couple of methods that will be particularly useful to you in this instance, take a look.

***Edit:*** It's worth noting the basic difference between `StringBuilder` and `StringBuffer` classes. `StringBuffer` is slower but thread safe, and that is the only meaningful difference. Otherwise the classes are practically identical.